# SQLite with VS 2010

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I'm working on a project and i need to use some database.I chose SQLite because of its easiness to use.But im having some trouble to get it work.I'm using System.Data.SQLite from http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/ but when i try to run the program i get the following exception message.I'm coding C# with Visual Studio 2010..

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=1fdb50b1b62b4c84,
>   Retargetable=Yes' or one of its
>   dependencies. The given assembly name
>   or codebase was invalid. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

I dont know why i get this and how to handle it.

I have to get this project ready for tomorrow and need your help...

Comment: Please post the code you are using to load the assembly, or else describes the steps you used if there is no code.

Comment: i just add it as reference and go with the "using" statement

Answer (score 3):

When you add a reference to the `System.Data.SQLite` assembly, make sure you set the property of "Copy Local" to true:

1. Right click the assembly `System.Data.SQLite`
2. Change "Copy Local" to True

This with the addition of [Dillie-O's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047772/sqlite-with-vs-2010/5047825#5047825) should get SQLite running on the .Net v4.0 Framework within VS 2010.

Answer (score 2):

There is a known issue with the .Net Framework 4 and SQLite according to [this post](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/2340/9316.aspx), and this [referenced post](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/2322.aspx). The solution is to add the following section into your .config  file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

This will properly load the 2.0 assembly with the 4.0 framework. Apparently the current SQLite library is built as a .Net 2.0 assembly.

Comment: @thecodekid: What version of the runtime are you targeting for build?

Answer (score 1):

If you need DBML layer stuff and LINQ to SQL Lite in your project, you're better off use DEVART's LinqExpress tools from [www.devart.com](http://www.devart.com).

Its free and it lets you build your model visually, then use the Linq generated classes in your project - wether VS Express or full monty mode.

Once LinqExpress for SQLLite is added to your project's references, it embarks the sqlLite dll too.

Please note: I have no shares in Devart company, but when I needed help with the free product, they helped me at no charge.

Answer (score 1):

I also suffer from this exception.
Here is my solution:

Modify app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

In "Solution Explorer -> {Project} -> Reference -> System.Data.SQLite" -> Properties -> Copy Local" , select "True"

You need to deploy `project.exe` and `project.exe.config` together.

I don't know why you need to deploy .config, but it doesn't work if I deploy `project.exe` without `project.exe.config`.

Answer (score 0):

I met same problem as well. I am using VS express 2010 and sqlite(1.0.66.0). In fact, it works fine during my development and debugging, but after I deployed compiled dll into production server. I got this error. I realised that it was caused by different sqlite dll version, so I fixed it with below steps:

1) Install same sqlite version on the development machine with production server(the version is 1.0.87);
2)  copy  system.data.sqlite.dll from version 1.0.87 folder into .NET Framework assembly reference folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0) which is used in VS express 2010 for .NET Framework 4.0

3) recompile the project to get new DLL
4) copy dll from step 3 onto the production server, then the issue was gone.

Also you may refer this blog:  http://www.tsjensen.com/blog/post/2011/06/04/SQLite+On+Visual+Studio+2010+Setup+Instructions.aspx