# Could not load file or assembly System.Data.SQLite

Tags: sqlite, exception, load, assemblies, system.data.sqlite

I have a working windows form application (C# .NET 4) using an SQLite3 Database file for storing and reading data.

When i deploy the application on the any machine other then the dev machine, i get an exeption: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly"

I have tried changing various settings, manually loading the dll (Assembly.LoadFile aswell as Assembly.LoadFrom) and placing the dll files next to the exe. Also, i have tried running the application under x86 aswell as x64 and under different target platforms.

I have tried using [Could not load assembly System.Data.SQLite.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904392/could-not-load-assembly-system-data-sqlite-dll)
All without luck.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

You also need to copy System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll and System.Data.SQLite.DLL to the deployed exe folder.

Comment: Only if he uses the System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll. with the other your right though

Answer (score 2):

'System.Data.SQLite.dll" requires "msvcr100.dll" which is one of it's Dependencies. This will be available only if you installed latest "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable" or any other product which internally provides this.

For example, VS2010 will install C++ Redistributable by default.You could try pasting the "msvcr100.dll" in your application bin folder and distribute if you dont want to install VC++ 2010 Redist in all the PC's.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem on moving my application from **.NetFramework** to **.NetCore**. Later downloading a .NetCore supported .NetStandard2.0 sqlite version downloaded from **http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/99229e8a9f2b2617** solved the issue. Better to try downloading and see if things would work. Also check for inner exceptions if any and resolve them

Answer (score 0):

What version of Visual Studio are you using? Perhaps your answer lies in [SQLite with VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047772/sqlite-with-vs-2010) ...